# Why do ls and mkdir take a long time even though there are only a few files in the working directory?

Tags: nfs

I have a written a lot files in a network file system; It is written in a directory structure such that each leaf-directory in the directory structure has a few (around a thousand) files. The part of the directory structure that contains the relevant files is quite flat.

If i run ls or mkdir foo, the corresponding operation takes a long time (around 10 minutes).

Why is this happening? How can I run operations like ls or mkdir in a more time efficient manner?

Comment: A few files would be 10-50 (a thousand isn't "a few").  If you have a hierarchy, that adds to the scanning needed to update the directory.

Comment: What file system are you using and what is the size of the parent dir? `ls -ld /dir/with/many/files`

Comment: One possibility is user name and gid lookups taking "too" long; see if that's the issue by running ls with the flags to inhibit those lookups.

Answer (score 2):

You're using a network filesystem, so your speed may be bounded by the network rather than disk.

When you run `ls`, the basic operation is to read in all the files, sort them and then print them out. This means that every `ls` will need to read several thousand file entries. Caching can help but it's still a slow process.

Similarly, when you run `mkdir` the directory needs to be checked you ensure you've not already got that directory.

**A solution would be to reduce the number of files per directory, making the structure *narrow and deep* rather then *shallow and wide*.**